# Replacing string in CSV file and writing to file

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to add a string (@example.com) to every row in the 2nd column in a CSV file and replacing the old string with the new string so the CSV file is saved with the new string. Example:

Old:

```
 John Smith, JohnSmith, Staff
```

New:

```
John Smith, JohnSmith@example.com, Staff
```

Here's my actual code:

```
f2 = open('/root/Downloads/UserAccounts/Users-7-21-2014.csv','w')
f3 = open('/root/Downloads/UserAccounts/Users-12-06-2012.csv')
f4 = open('/root/Downloads/UserAccounts/Users-05-13-2007.csv')

# adds the first and last name together and adds @examples to userID
# but does not replace first and last name into one
for row in f2.readlines():
    m = row.split(',')[0], row.split(',')[1]
    j = row.split(',')[2] + "@example.com"
    row = row.replace(row.split(',')[2], j)
    f2.write(row) #error is here

# adds first and last name together
# but does not replace first and last name into one
for row in f3.readlines():
    n = row.split(',')[0], row.split(',')[1]
    # print n

# adds @example.com to username
for row in f4.readlines():
    t = row.split(',')[1] + "@example.com"
    row = row.replace(row.split(',')[1], t)
    # print row
```

As you can see, I am only playing around with the f2 file in trying to overwrite the CSV with the new data. But when I try to open the file with either 'w' or 'a', I keep getting a **IOError: File not open for writing** for *f2.write(row)*. But when I just print the row variable, it print exactly what I need. T am probably getting this error because I am both reading and trying to write over it at the same time.

How would I add the @example.com to every row in the 2nd column and save it so that it is actually changed in the same CSV file?

I know its really messy code but I am just a beginner. This is my way of handling it, so give me a break. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Reading and writing, from and to, the same file is not recommended. If you wish to do it anyway I would suggest you do it as follows:

```
with open('/root/Downloads/UserAccounts/Users-7-21-2014.csv','r') as f2:
    Rows = f2.readlines() 

with open('/root/Downloads/UserAccounts/Users-7-21-2014.csv','w') as f2:
   for row in Rows:
       #do something with the row here
       f2.write(row)
```